# Dart interop: How correctly to make a wrapper?

Tags: javascript, dart

How correctly to make a wrapper? I need to wrap this method:

js:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        floatingFilterComponentParams: {
            suppressFilterButton: true, // <--- это
        },
    },
];
```

I try this option:

```
@JS('ColumnDef.floatingFilterComponentParams')
//class floatingFilterComponentParams extends ColumnDef {
class floatingFilterComponentParams {
  external set suppressFilterButton(bool value);
}
```

If this is correct, how do I run it in dart code? There is no such method in columnDefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `js_util` library in `js` package. The following code should work:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:js/js_util.dart' as js_util;

@JS()
external List get columnDef;

set suppressFilterButton(bool value) {
  final floatingFilterComponentParams = js_util.getProperty(columnDef[0], 'floatingFilterComponentParams');
  js_util.setProperty(floatingFilterComponentParams, suppressFilterButton, value)
}
```